# compatibility - Browser versions with Selenium webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I want to know the web driver compatibility with browsers. So that I can decide which web driver I can use in my test suites.

> |Selenium Webdriver | Firefox | Chrome | IE |
>
> | 2.35 | ? | ? | ? |
>
> | 2.36 | ? | ? | ? |
>
> | 2.37 | ? | ? | ? |

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this CHANGELOG for
         web driver compatibility with browsers.

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/rb/CHANGES